# Extracting named data frame indices into a 2 column array based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to **extract row and column name combinations** from a data frame that is **equal to 2** and plug these into a 2x9 data frame. With the first column having the row names and the second column having the column names of the data frame.

This is a smaller scale example of the **data frame(DF)**:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| **B** | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| **C** | 2 | 8 | 1 |

And I want to fill in an empty 2x9 **data frame(SD)** like this:

| RowNames | ColumnNames |
| --- | --- |
| *NA* | *NA* |
| *NA* | *NA* |
| C | A |
| A | B |
| *NA* | *NA* |
| *NA* | *NA* |
| *NA* | *NA* |
| B | C |
| *NA* | *NA* |

I am using the following code (with **k** being the conundrum I am dealing with) :

```
DF <- data.frame(A <- c(5, 8, 2),
                B <- c(2, 4, 8),
                C <- c(1, 2, 1), 
                row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))

SD <- data.frame(RowNames = c(rep(NA,9)),
                ColumnNames = c(rep(NA,9)))

for(i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    ifelse(DF[i,j] == 2, SD[k,1] <- rownames(DF[i,]), SD[k,1] <- NA )
    ifelse(DF[i,j] == 2, SD[k,2] <- colnames(DF[,j]), SD[k,2] <- NA )
  }
}
```

**Problem:** I cannot think of a formula **using i and j** that allows for **k** to run from **1 to 9** within the loop.

I have only been coding for a few months, so excuse me if I am missing anything here.

Comment: You should see the differences between the `=` and `<-`. In your data.frame call, you should use `=`. For your task, take a look at `?which` and in particular the `arr.ind` argument.

Comment: Try `k <- i + (ncol(DF)*(j-1))` or `k <- j + (nrow(DF)*(i-1))` depending on whether it is row-wise or column-wise.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for the comment, I edited the post to have `<-` be `=`. As to using `arr.ind` in `?which`, I am not sure how I should use this in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to this comment:

> Try `k <- i + (ncol(DF)*(j-1))` or `k <- j + (nrow(DF)*(i-1))` depending
> on whether it is row-wise or column-wise.

Subset the row names instead of the table.

```
DF <- data.frame(A = c(5, 8, 2),
                 B = c(2, 4, 8),
                 C = c(1, 2, 1), 
                 row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))

SD <- data.frame(RowNames = c(rep(NA,9)),
                 ColumnNames = c(rep(NA,9)))

for(i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    k <- i + (ncol(DF)*(j-1))
    SD[k,1] <- ifelse(DF[i,j] == 2, rownames(DF)[i], NA)
    SD[k,2] <- ifelse(DF[i,j] == 2, rownames(DF)[j], NA)
  }
} 

SD
  RowNames ColumnNames
1     <NA>        <NA>
2     <NA>        <NA>
3        C           A
4        A           B
5     <NA>        <NA>
6     <NA>        <NA>
7     <NA>        <NA>
8        B           C
9     <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of this. I do not have enough reputation points to vote on your answer, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome!